# make clean in omnet++ project and version mismatch

Tags: omnet++

I keep getting the following error when running the following project:

[image]

when clicking on "Proceed" I get:

[image]

from which I don't know what should I do.

Here is the full manifest of the running project:

```
21:35:18 **** Incremental Build of configuration release for project OSPF ****
make MODE=release all 
Node.cc
In file included from Node.cc:8:
In file included from ./Node.h:14:
./traffic_m.h:16:6: error: Version mismatch! Probably this file was generated by an earlier version of nedtool: 'make clean' should help.
#    error Version mismatch! Probably this file was generated by an earlier version of nedtool: 'make clean' should help.
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Makefile:105: out/clang-release//Node.o] Error 1

21:36:15 Build Finished (took 56s.271ms)
```

> Should I change the version? If so, how to do that? My current omnet++
>   version is 5.4.1.
>
> How to use **make clean** to fix up my work?

I don't know what "make clean" is nor I know how should I apply that. Would you help me with this please? It's my semester's final project....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the version of OMNeT++ is not necessary.
`make clean` is an operation that removes C++ object files, final libraries or executables, and other files created during compilation.
What is important: `make clean` does not remove any of your source file.

To perform `make clean` just right click on your projekt in Project Explorer and select `Clean local`.